# Prevent window height change when mobile address bar appears / disapears

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I use Jquery to get the height of the devices displaying a website, to make sure that my homepage has a height of 100%, and when scrolled thru, header menu will go fixed to top.
For that, I measure Window InnerHeight with a functiun, which is called on document ready, and window resize events (to keep the design clean when user changes portrait / landscpae mode on mobile, or resizes his window on desktop).

Problem on mobile : the adress bar on android is displayed on page load, and hides on scroll down, then reappears on scroll up. This makes some page elements change sizes on evey opportunity and moves contents in the page. Not pleasant for the user.

```
function setHeight() {
windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
$('.home-intro').css('min-height', windowHeight);
}
$( window ).resize(function() {
setHeight();
});
```

Is there a way to get the window size, not affected by the adress bar being displayed or not ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a year late, but I've struggled with this issue as well. I've found that using "window.document.documentElement.clientHeight" instead of "$(window).innerHeight();" makes it so the when the address bar disappears your min-height targeted elements won't resize again to fill the extra 50px or so.

Here's what I'm using on my project:

```
function adjustBackgrounds() {
    windowHeight = window.document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    $('#section-01-home').css('min-height', windowHeight);
}     
// Triggers Sizing on Load (783 = 800px accounting for 17px of scrollbar)
if ($(window).width() <= 783) {
    adjustBackgrounds();
} else {

}
// Triggers Sizing on Browser Resize (783 = 800px accounting for 17px of scrollbar)
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 783) {
    adjustBackgrounds();
  } else {

  }
});
```

Comment: I only needed the function for smaller screen sizes, that's why there's code to make it only work under 800px but that can be removed.